# What is an example of a commutative ring with a non-zero element which isn't a unit?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Any example will do so long that an explanation is given.

Comment: What about $\mathbb Z$?

Comment: OP has responded to comments in answers (and shown some effort etc.) so there is no need to close this post.

Answer (score 2):

The most trivial example is probably $\Bbb Z$.

For a less trivial example, consider the ring $\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z$. Then $1$ and $3$ are units since $3\cdot 3\equiv1$, while $2\cdot2\equiv0$, so $2$ cannot be a unit (no unit is ever a zero divisor).

Comment: I guess I'm not really seeing how $\mathbb{Z}$ works.

Comment: What does it mean for an element of a ring to be a unit?

Comment: Ah, nevermind. It works because there is no element in $\mathbb{Z}$ such that $2a=1$.